# DialogInterface.OnShowListener() cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android

I'm remotely collaborating with a friend on an Android project and when I pulled his changes to my local repo, I get the following error message for a call made on an AlertDialog object:

```
DialogInterface.OnShowListener() cannot be resolved to a type
```

Here's the full code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
...
...
protected AlertDialog mDialogForgotPassword;
...
...
mDialogForgotPassword = new AlertDialog.Builder(LogInActivity.this)
.setTitle(getString(R.string.forgot_password))
.setView(input)
.setCancelable(false)
.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // NOTE: LEAVE THIS AS EMPTY
        // WE OVERRIDEN THIS METHOD USING THE setOnShowListener
    }

})
.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
})
.create(); // created AlertDialog

// ERROR APPEARS NEXT, red line under "new DialogInterface.OnShowListener()"
mDialogForgotPassword.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
        final Button positiveButton = mDialogForgotPassword.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        positiveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String EMAIL = input.getText().toString();
                if( ValidationHelper.isEmail(EMAIL) ){
                    resetUserPassword(EMAIL);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}); // end setOnShowListener
mDialogForgotPassword.show();
```

The friend says that when he presses `Ctrl` + `Space` in Eclipse after typing `mDialogForgotPassword`, the method `setOnShowListener()` appears as a suggestion. To me, however, it does not, but the import statements seem to be complete. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to eliminate the error:

1. Made sure my Java compiler in Eclipse is set to 1.6. Right-clicked on project --> Java Compiler --> Check "Enable project specific settings" --> Set "Compiler compliance level" to 1.6 --> Check "Use default compiler compliance settings."
2. Right-clicked on project --> Android --> Checked "Android 4.1" for the project build target. As of this writing, Jelly Bean is the latest release.
3. In my Android manifest, I upped the minimum SDK to 8 (Froyo, 2.2) and set the targetSdk to 16, Jelly Bean. API level 4 was too low for a minimum anyway, and according to [Android distribution data](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), has a very small and shrinking market share.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse then try pressing

```
CTRL + SHIFT + O
```

(its not "zero", its the letter "O") while in the file that is causing the problem. This should resolve all import problems.

If this doesn't help then you should make sure that you and your friend have the project configured to use the same API LEVEL. `DialogInterface.OnShowListener()` is available since API LEVEL 8 so make sure that your project is configured to use at least that API level.

Comment: I'm afraid neither solutions work. I right-clicked the project -> Properties -> Android and my target build is actually API level 13. In the manifest, however, the minimum SDK is set to 4 and maximum to 15.